# Python sparse matrix files all same size

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm using numpy to save a set of about 7300 sparse matrices. Each sparse matrix has the same number of rows but a different number of columns. The data that gets written to the file are the nonzero values in the matrix, the location of each nonzero value, and the shape of the matrix. Yet, every single file is exactly the same size on the disk.

Here's the code I'm using to save and load the files. I would be happy to provide more code and/or output information as needed.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

# insert other code here

def saveSparseGraph(graph, fn):
    """
    Try to save the graph using numpy.save

    Inputs:
    - graph: the csr_matrix to save
    - fn: the filename base (no extensions)

    Returns: none
    """
    np.savez(fn, data=graph.data, indices=graph.indices, indptr=graph.indptr, shape=graph.shape)
    print "Saved the files"


def loadSparseGraph(fn):
    """
    Try to load the previously saved graph

    Inputs:
    - fn: the file name/path base (no extensions)

    Returns: 
    - the loaded sparse matrix
    """
    loader = np.load(fn+".npz")
    print "Sparse graph loaded"
    return sp.csr_matrix((loader['data'], loader['indices'], loader['indptr']), shape=loader['shape'])
```

When loading the data from the saved files and looking at it, it appears to all be there. (I say "appears" because I don't know the full extent of the original data since the matrixes are huge.)

Is there any reason the identical file sizes could make sense?

Comment: How about the number of nonzero values, the matrix `.nnz`?  The length of the `indptr` array is the number of rows, but the length of the `data` and `indices` arrays is `nnz`.

Comment: Are you sure the matrices have a different number of used values? I tried filling some matrices with a random number of values, and then saving them and they all have different file sizes.

Comment: The matrices do have different numbers of used values. They are on the order of 7865000 nnz values in each matrix, but the last 3 digits are different for each matrix.

Comment: Maybe the file size differs in the last 3 digits as well.

Comment: Turns out it was caused by a deeper bug in my code, now the files differ in the last 3 digits of the file size (ls -l folder/). Thanks for the help everyone!